# handleSubmit not submitting the formik form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I've set up a formik form for a signup page but it isn't submitting the form when I click the submit button. Also as I'm using formik form so there are some props from formik and some props from my parent component. can we use two props from two different components in the one component?

the signup component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";

function Copyright() {
    return (
      <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
        <Link color="inherit" href="sad">
          New
        </Link>{" "}
        {new Date().getFullYear()}
        {"."}
      </Typography>
    );
  }

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    paper: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      alignItems: "center"
    },
    avatar: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
    },
    form: {
      width: "100%",
      marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
    },
    submit: {
      margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)
    }
  }));

  const SupFirst = props => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState("");
    const [changed, setChanged] = useState(false);
    const {setSignup, signup, email, setEmail}=props;
    const handleSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        const {email} =values;
        setEmail(values);
        var body = {
          email: email
        };
        console.log(body);
        const options = {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(body)
        };
        const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/emailcheck";
        try {
          const response = await fetch(url, options);
          const text = await response.text();
          setSubmitting(false);
          setChanged(false);
          console.log(text);
          if (text === "does not exist") {
            setSignup(true);
          } else if (text === "exists") {
            props.history.push(`/`);

          } else {
            setLoginError("Email is invalid");
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };
return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{email:""}}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      //********Using Yup for validation********/

      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
          .email()
          .required("Required"),
      })}
    >
      {props => {
        const {
          values,
          touched,
          errors,
          isSubmitting,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit
        } = props;
        return (
          <>
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
              <CssBaseline />
              <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                  <LockOutlinedIcon />
                </Avatar>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                  Sign in
                </Typography>
                <form
                  className={classes.form}
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                  noValidate
                >
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    id="email"
                    value={values.email}
                    label="Email Address"
                    name="email"
                    autoComplete="email"
                    onChange={e=>{setChanged(true);handleChange(e)}}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}
                  />
                  {errors.email && touched.email && (
                    <div className="input-feedback" style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.email}</div>
                  )}
{!changed && loginError && (
                    <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
                      <span>{loginError}</span>
                    </div>
                  )}

                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submit}
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                  >
            Next
          </Button>
          <Grid container justify="flex-end">
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="/" variant="body2">
                Already have an account? Sign in
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={5}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
          </>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default SupFirst;
```

Comment: How I handled the similar problem.
Change your button from using type="submit" to type="button" and add the onClick like this
 type="button" onClick={submitForm}
The submitForm is a prop availed by formik that you include on the return props like this
{values,
          errors,
          touched,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          submitForm,
          isSubmitting
With this done, also don't forget to add the onSubmit prop like this. This will run your submit handler when the form validation passes
 <Formik onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

Comment: Also don't forget that the onSubmit prop on the form will be called if the form is valid only!